# Splitting a Column into various columns

Tags: sql

```
-- Create table dbo.FullNameTest
IF OBJECT_ID('FullNameTest') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
   DROP TABLE dbo.FullNameTest;
END;

CREATE TABLE FullNameTest
(
   ID           INT          Not Null IDENTITY
   , FullName   NVARCHAR(80) Not Null
   , CONSTRAINT PK_ID  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ID)
);
GO

INSERT INTO FullNameTest
VALUES('Mr Hog Finn Gad'), ('Grace Bruce'), ('Dr.Paul'), ('Master Clark James'), ('Mrs.Rignald')

SELECT * FROM FullNameTest
```

Rules

1. Treat entries (Mrs, Mr, Miss etc) as Titles and ignore the dot after title
2. When we have title and a single name, return it as Title, LastName
3. When we have title and two names return it as Title, FirstName and LastName
4. When we have title and three names, return Title, FirstName and treat the rest as LastName
5. When we have no title, reurn data as FirstName, LastName
6. No function required.

So we can get values in this form:

```
Title   FirstName   LastName
------------------------------
Mr      Hog         Finn Gad
Null    Grace       Bruce
Dr      Null        Paul
Master  Clark       James
Mrs     Null        Rignald
```

Thank you

Comment: According to your example, you don't only want to split title, first name, and last name, you also want to CLEAN your data. I would suggest tackling them separately. Obviously the same method for separating "Mr. John Smith" will not work for "MsCollins".

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: ***To test the results yourself, use the following to create your full name table, then run the code to create the title table, and then run the solution code below that. The results are exactly what you asked for.

```
CREATE TABLE #FullNameTest
(
   ID           INT          Not Null IDENTITY
   , FullName   NVARCHAR(80) Not Null
);
GO

INSERT INTO #FullNameTest
VALUES('Mr Hog Finn Gad'), ('Grace Bruce'), ('Dr.Paul'), ('Master Clark James'), ('Mrs.Rignald')
```

This may not work in every situation, and it requires the use of a reference table with Titles, but it should get you started. Again, I would suggest putting in some data validation restraints so you don't get unexpected input. If that's not possible, then run some algorithms to clean your data first. It gets messy when you try to do stuff like this in SQL.

Create a title reference table with title and length of title.

```
create table #title (Title varchar(15), Long as len(Title))

insert into #title (Title) values
('Mr'),
('Mister'),
('Ms'),
('Miss'),
('Mrs'),
('Misses'),
('Dr'),
('Doctor'),
('Senator'),
('Officer'),
('Master')
```

Your table looks like this:

```
Mr      2
Mister  6
Ms      2
Miss    4
Mrs     3
Misses  6
Dr      2
Doctor  6
Senator 7
Officer 7
Master  6
```

Then you've got this monstrous block of code that attempts to account for every case of input you may have. AGAIN - Try to clean your data first if possible. Otherwise you will have to modify this code every time you receive something unexpected.

```
select   y.RawName
       , y.Title
       , y.FName 
       , case when RawName like '%'+y.Title+'% %'+y.FName+'%' then RIGHT(RawName, len(RawName)-LEN(y.Title+'% %'+y.FName+' ')+1)
              when Title is not null then RIGHT(RawName, len(RawName)-len(title)) 
              when Title is null and RawName like '% %' then RIGHT(RawName, len(RawName)-len(Fname)-1)
          end LName
from (      
        select RawName
             , Title
             , case when right(RawName, len(RawName)-len(title)-1) like '% %' 
                        then left(right(RawName, len(RawName)-len(title)-1), CHARINDEX(' ', right(RawName, len(RawName)-len(title)-1),1))
                    when RawName like '% %' 
                        then left(RawName, CHARINDEX(' ', RawName, 1))
                end FName
        from    (  
                select 
                      replace(f.FullName, '.', '') RawName
                    , t.title Title
                    , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by f.fullname order by len(t.title) desc) row_n
                from #FullNameTest f
                    left join #title t
                        on left(f.fullname, t.long) = t.title
                ) x
        where row_n = 1
    ) y
```

Based on your samples from above, you are left with the following:

```
 RawName              Title     FName    LName
 DrPaul               Dr        NULL     Paul
 Grace Bruce          NULL      Grace    Bruce
 Master Clark James   Master    Clark    James
 Mr Hog Finn Gad      Mr        Hog      Finn Gad
 MrsRignald           Mrs       NULL     Rignald
```

If this is helps you with your problem, please accept it as the answer. :)

Comment: This didn't produce the right result and  the performance is not as great too. Thank you

Comment: Uhh, it produces exactly what you asked for in your example. Try it again. If you didn't get the correct result, then you made a mistake in your code.

Comment: I did give you the disclaimer that it has to be modified for other situations. It will only work for what you have provided, and you'll need to add your own case statements to handle other types of input.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I think the error has to do with the performance of the query as well as it's being ran against a table with over 25 million records. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I eventually used:

```
SELECT Title,
       CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',PARTNAME) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE LEFT(PARTNAME, CHARINDEX(' ',PARTNAME))
        END AS [FirstName],
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',PARTNAME) = 0 THEN PARTNAME
       ELSE RIGHT(PARTNAME, LEN(PARTNAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', PARTNAME))
       END AS [LastName]
FROM
(
SELECT TITLE, LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(FULLNAME,ISNULL(TITLE,''),''),'.','')) AS PARTNAME
FROM (
SELECT CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('DR ',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Dr'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('DR.',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Dr'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('MR ',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Mr'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('MR.',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Mr'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('MRS ',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Mrs'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('MRS.',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Mrs'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('MISS ',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Miss'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('MISS.',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Miss'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('MASTER ',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Master'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('MASTER.',FullName) = 1 THEN 'Master'
    ELSE NULL
    END AS [Title], FullName
FROM FullNameTest
) B
) C
```

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Using your code, a name like 'JohnPaul' gives a null value. Using mine, at least you get something in LastName.